# How can I override an attribute on a node with Chef?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-attributes

We have a Chef environment setup. Our deployments work fine, with node attributes properly overridden by roles and environments.

In order to test an upcoming change, we want to change a setting on 1 particular node in our deployment. We don't want to write a different recipe, role or environment for that test as there is really only 1 setting different.

I tried via Chef Manage's web UI and set the particular node's attribute as follows:

```
{
    "tags": null,
    "our_app":{
        "url": "http://test-server"
    }
}
```

In our cookbook the `attributes/default.rb` is set as follows:

```
default[:our_app][:url] = ''
```

In our environment file, we override the setting as follows:

```
override_attributes({
    "our_app" => {
        "url" => "http://default-server",
    }
})
```

We use the following `.erb` template inside our recipe:

```
{
    "serverUrl": "<%= node[:our_app][:url]%>"
}
```

However, when we run chef-client on that node, it still ends up with `http://default-server` in the output.

I understand the [attribute precedence as explained in the docs](https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html#attribute-precedence) . But I am not sure how to achieve what I want.

Am I supposed to *not* use `override_attributes()` in my environment file?

Is there a way to have a *node-specific override attribute* ?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way of having a node-specific override. The node specific data is always (and the only thing at) the `normal` level. You should, in general, not be using override levels at all, and certainly not for something calling itself a default value.

Also we really recommend not using roles/envs anymore. You should switch to the Policyfile system as soon as you get a chance.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I have little control over what IT currently has setup and our current standard is roles/env. So I am trying to work with that.
I tried changing my environment file to `default_attributes()` instead and setting the node's `override` attributes. But that does not seem to work either. The override is showing in the `knife edit -a` command and in the `knife show -l` but it does not seem to be used.

Comment: You can't set a node's override attributes, it has no such thing. You see echo'd data in the node object that is saved back off the node at the end of a successful converge, to be used for search() and for reporting stuff, but it's not an input. Only roles, envs, and cookbooks can set at the override level(s).

Comment: so there is no way for me to force a node attribute for 1 particular node without doing it in the env/roles/recipes?

Comment: There is, but only if you've been careful to set the majority of your attrs at a `default` level, which you should be doing. `override` is only for emergencies, like `!important` in CSS.

Comment: can you point me to the documentation or article about how to do this? I actually went and rewrote most of my envs/roles as `default` instead of `override` (I inherited the code...). So, I would be ready to try your solution if you have one. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just put it in the `normal` level in the node object as per usual. That is "above" `default` to it would take priority.

Comment: doh! thanks @coderanger. I feel silly about that last question now. I realized that after I tried so many different setup it was all screwed up. I just went through the WebUI (or `knife`), set the attribute and it worked like a charm...